# How to use spritesheet animation created in Cocos Studio

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, sprite-sheet

I am learning to work with Cocos Studio. The problem is:

I created an animation from multiple sprite in Cocos Studio. Now I want to load it to my cocos2d-x project. I worked on this issue from yesterday but until now there is no result.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Load the scene/layer with:

```
auto node = CSLoader::createNodeWithVisibleSize("file.csb");
```

Load the animation timeline and play with:

```
auto animTimeline = CSLoader::createTimeline("file.csb");
node->runAction(animTimeline);
animTimeline->gotoFrameAndPlay(0, true);
```

If you have embedded layers find the correct child node, load the appropriate timeline and play with:

```
node->enumerateChildren("//child", [=](Node* _node)
{
    auto animTimeline = CSLoader::createTimeline("child.csb");
    _node->runAction(animTimeline);
    animTimeline->gotoFrameAndPlay(0, true);
    return true;
});
```

(see Node::enumerateChildren() declaration in CCNode.h for usage details)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but it's not what I'm looking for. In Cocos Studio, I created a lot of animation, each animation was created from multiple spritesheet. For example I have anim1, anim2, anim3 ... How can I load anim1 and play from C++ ?

Comment: You can also play animations by name via the timeline action: animTimeline->play("anim1", loop); (https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/editor-support/cocostudio/ActionTimeline/CCActionTimeline.h)